# how to fix 'Chrome Content Security Policy Directive' in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension that hits Wikipedia's API through an ajax call using JQuery.  I have included a copy of JQuery in my extension's local js folder.  in the popup I have an input and I take that value and do a get request in the popup.js and I get a "Refused to load the script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback."

I have `WebRequest and <all_urls>` set in the permissions in `manifest.json` file.  This is what my permissions look like in the manifest:

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "webNavigation",
    "webRequest",
    "<all_urls>",
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/*"
  ],
```

I saw that adding a `"content_security_policy": "script-src-elem 'self' https://www.wikipedia.org/"` would make it easier on it but that didn't solve the problem.

```
$('#urlCopyButton').click(function search() {
    var searchWord = document.querySelector('#searchWord').value;
    console.log(searchWord);
    var results = [];


$.ajax({
          crossDomain: true,
          header: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
          url:`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&maxlag=5&search=${searchWord}&callback=?`,
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'json',
          beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('https://en.wikipedia.org', 'https://en.wikipedia.org');},
          success: (data) => {
              $("#output").html("");
            var i =0;
            for (var i = 0; i < data[1].length; i++) {
              $("#output").append(`<li><a href= "${data[3][i]  } ">${data[1][i] + " " + data[2][i]}<a></li>`);
            }
            console.log(data);
          },
          error: (err) =>{
            console.log(err.responseJSON);
          }


      })
```

})

I expect it to be a success and the data to so up in the console but it doesn't it throws this error:

Refused to load the script 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&maxlag=5&search=dfa&callback=jQuery33108394586597996985_1549655186216&_=1549655186217' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

send @ jquery.js:2"

Comment: I can post a link to a github repo with all my code if you need me to

Comment: See [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr): simply declare the site in ”permissions” field and don't use CORS headers in the request. No need to modify CSP either.

Comment: I've already got it in the permissions:   "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "webNavigation",
    "webRequest",
    "<all_urls>",
    " https://en.wikipedia.org/* "
  ],

Comment: I removed the CORS headers from the ajax call and CSP from the manifset.json.  It still is an error: Refused to load the script 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&maxlag=5&search=doggo&callback=jQuery33105406979547963953_1549720122284&_=1549720122286' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.. however, when i click on the link it takes me to what I expected to get back.

Comment: so is there a way to let Chrome be okay with the script?

Comment: Vanilla JS works as shown in the documentation so either you still have an extra header, or maybe you didn't reload the extension on chrome://extensions page. BTW your URL has two `?` which is probably wrong, although not a reason for the observed problem.

Comment: yeah this is what my ajax looks like now:   $.ajax({
              url:`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&maxlag=5&search=${searchWord}&callback=?`,
              type: 'GET',
              dataType: 'json',
              success: (data) => {
                  $("#output").html("");
                var i =0;
                for (var i = 0; i < data[1].length; i++) {
                  $("#output").append(`<li><a href= "${data[3][i]  } ">${data[1][i] + " " + data[2][i]}<a></li>`);
                }
                console.log(data);
              },

Comment: Indeed it's a problem with jQuery and dataType:'json'. The standard XHR or fetch works without problems and without any extra CORS-related stuff.

Comment: Awesome, that's good to know, I'll try using one of those, thanks for you're help and patience

Comment: You can use jQuery too, just without the dataType. Instead use JSON.parse on the response.

Comment: so the JSON.parse would go before or after the success part in jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia's `callback=?` parameter is an ancient hack to load `dataType: 'json'` as a script, which is forbidden by default CSP in extensions. While many existing answers suggest relaxing the default extension CSP, it's obviously a bad solution that opens the extension to various remote attacks (like MitM).

**Simply remove `&callback=?` parameter so that wikipedia returns a valid JSON by default.**

No need for CORS-related tweaks like headers or `crossDomain: true`, no need to modify CSP.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?' +
       'action=opensearch&format=json&maxlag=5&search=' + encodeURIComponent(searchWord),
  success(data) {
    // ...............
    // data is an object/array, you can process it directly here
    // ...............
  },
});
```

manifest.json should allow the URL:

- `"permissions": ["https://*.wikipedia.org/"]`
- `"permissions": ["<all_urls>"]`